# Android - VectorDrawable Splashscreen Theme

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to follow the good practices of a splash screen from this link: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/, but I am not able implement it with vectors on APIs lower than 21.

I saw several splash screens without picture quality loss, like youtube, google photos, etc (flawless image quality and running on API 16 really look likes a vector to me), could you help me trying to achieve this result?

Youtube splash screen example:
https://www.bignerdranch.com/assets/img/blog/2015/08/youtube_splash.gif

I have switched to this method of implementing a splash screen (without inflating a xml into a activity with setContentView) because the last one is very slow, it takes like 1-2 seconds before the application start.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: That gif appears to be an iPhone and shows a transition that isn't (easily) possible using the splash screen technique in the question.

Comment: @Lewis McGeary While that phone might be an iPhone, my android api 16 can accomplish the same result. You might try some of the apps I gave as example.

Comment: the gif shows the logo changing it's size and position to morph into the app bar, that isn't the same as the linked article.

Comment: . With regards to the question, I'm not sure if VectorDrawable can be used for that situation (I've tried unsuccessfully before, but didn't put a lot of time into it). However, you should still be able to achieve a sharp splash screen with .pngs. If you're having particular issues you may want to give details in the question.

Comment: @LewisMcGeary Hi, thanks for the help. I ended up using pngs with drawable density, no picture loss cause its fixed size. I was having a problem before all this (pngs were having bad quality, they were auto resizing to the screen width), deleted the projected and redone. The png no longer have bad quality. I really do not know how I manage to get a bitmap to set the parent width with padding in a layer list but oh well, it's now working :).

Comment: That's great! yeah, it's easy to go wrong and end up with a stretched image when doing this.